How to modify request body in WebClient with ExchangeFilterFunction
I would like to override a Webclient that is coming from a third party library with my own Webclient. My idea is to catch the request before it is sent, and enhance the body with some custom body (key-values) from my side.
The library builds their Webclient that is sending a POST request with a BodyInserters.FormInserter<String> body that is just a key value MultiValueMap.
The library allows me to override their webClient so I'm trying to create my own Webclient and put a ExchangeFilterFunction in between.
ExchangeFilterFunction requestProcessor = ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {
     ClientRequest.Builder clientRequestBuilder = ClientRequest.from(clientRequest);
     BodyInserter<?, ? super ClientHttpRequest> oldBody = clientRequest.body();
     MultiValueMap<String, String> newBodyValue = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
     newBodyValue.add("customKey", "customValue");

     // Check whether "oldBody" already has key-value from newBodyValue
     // And if not, enhance "oldBody" with this key-value and build a new clientRequest

     BodyInserters.FormInserter<String> newBody = BodyInserters.fromFormData(....)
     clientRequestBuilder.body(newBody);
     return Mono.just(clientRequestBuilder.build());
});

WebClient customWebclient = WebClient.builder()
     .filter(requestProcessor)
     .build();

But I'm getting stuck now.
How to check whether the request body already has a key-value in it and if not then add my custom one. Can anyone give me an idea how to resolve this?
I did try to find some documentations but unfortunately no success
